# How do I submit the right value?

Tags: java, html, jsp, spring-mvc

```
    <c:forEach items="${movieList}" var="movie" varStatus="status">            
                    <tr class="<c:if test="${status.count % 2 == 0}">even</c:if>"> 
                        <td>${movie.title}</td> 
                        <td>${movie.genre}</td> 
                        <td>${movie.year}</td> 
                        <td>${movie.boxoffice}</td>
                        <td>
                            <form:form action=edit.htm>
                                <input type="hidden" name="edit" value="movie name">
                                <input type="submit" value="Edit">
                            </form:form>
                            <form:form action=delete.htm>
                                <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="movie name">
                                <input type="submit" value="Edit">
                            </form:form>
                    </tr>       
                </c:forEach>
```

This is the section of code I have at the moment. The idea is to display movie data, but also provide buttons to send the user to either a filled form page to edit the data or simply delete the respective data and redirect to the same page. I am just unsure as how to pass along the movie object. I know it is simple, but I can't find the reference I used previously...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

U can try this :

put this object in a hidden input

```
<input type="hidden" id="hidden_object" value="" name="hidden_object"></input>
```

than you can access the value with the method getParameter()

OR

put this object in your session

in your jsp

```
<% session.setAttribute("movie", ${movie}); %>
```

good luck

Comment: **I will have several movie objects from a list. Should I be using the first method, would I be using the "var = movie" from the loop? If so, then I can make sure that the individual movie object is correctly passed when submitted, correct? The second method I am not sure I understand how I can differentiate the different objects. Where would I be inserting the scriptlet to accomplish the issue at hand?